# Seeking further validation that my research on Instagram's updated graph API through Facebook is correct

Tags: php, react-native, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm aware that Instagram has been phasing out their Platform API in favor of the Instagram Graph API through Facebook, except for select non-Business and non-Creator accounts (for which Instagram still refers developers to their Platform API); even though I've researched these use cases individually, this is my first time interacting with these APIs, and before I spend the time developing, I'd prefer additional confirmation from the development community regarding if my research on the following use cases is correct:

1) Post content on authorized users' behalfs

-> possible only for authorized Business and Creator Instagram accounts (linked to a Facebook Page) via the Instagram Graph API, and not possible for general Instagram Users

2) Retrieve a list of followers of an authorized user

-> I didn't see anything about this functionality in either API

3) Retrieve a list of followers of personal Instagram account

-> I didn't see anything about this functionality in either API

4) Retrieve a list of pages an Instagram User follows

-> I didn't see anything about this functionality in either API

5) Query media objects based on hashtag

-> possible via the Instagram Graph API

Any additional input is appreciated; there are many other use cases I've confirmed independently, but these were my remaining questions.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions:

1) At the moment it's not really possible unless you are Facebook Marketing Partner or Instagram Partner. You can find more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing Content publishing is closed beta only for those members and Facebook is not accepting any new applicants now.

2) & 3) & 4) I'm afraid it's not possible either. You can only get general number of following/followers, but you are unable to list them, for instance if you want the list of usernames etc.. It is both for Instagram legacy API and for Instagram Graph API.

5) Yes, it works with Instagram Graph API but it has some limitations (listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search )